# disable menu hiding on searchview search

Tags: android

when I use searchview, when searchview is active it hides menu icon , but i need this menu when search active also. How prevnt it from hiding?
[image]

After searching it hides the red colored menu

[image]

Comment: Well, you can try adding SearchView not as a "menu item" but as "custom view" inside of the Toolbar.

Comment: For this I must change lot of code, are there exists quick solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want sort menu in search, you can hide it on searchview expand. If you will hide sort menu, option menu will stay exists.
Here is example

```
final MenuItem sortmenu = menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort);
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                sortmenu.setVisible(true);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sortmenu.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
```